# TabItem style not displaying the Header info

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Made a great looking tab in Blend, but my `ContentPresenter` must be off - its not displaying the `TabItem` Header text.

Edit 1: Implemented CodeNaked's suggestion, and Rachel's answer so you can just use this style as is if you like.

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#7F605F5F" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#7F7E7E7E" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.BorderBrush>
                <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6096E5" Offset="0.004"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF6096E5" Offset="0.823"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.228"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                </Border>
            <Border x:Name="BorderGlass" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" Background="#7FFDFDFD">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#BFFFFFFF" Offset="0.401"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#F2FFFFFF" Offset="0.254"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.BorderBrush>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header">
                <ContentPresenter.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF6096E5" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6096E5" Offset="0.823"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.228"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                </ContentPresenter.OpacityMask>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you add some code as to how to use this style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `ContentSource="Header"` to your ContentPresenter

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first Style isn't really valid. You should not define the control in the control you are Styling. In your first Style, you include a TabItem in the control template for a TabItem. Which you shouldn't do.

Rachel's answer addresses issues with your second Style.